# What is the Torah perspective on our response to coronavirus?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, health-safety-shmira

What spiritual response does *daas Torah* (Rabbonim, Gedolim, etc.) suggest we should utilize in facing coronavirus?

For instance, [Rav Yisroel Reisman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisroel_Reisman) (Ki Sisa 5780) mentioned saying פיטום הקטורת and [Rav Simcha Bunim Cohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simcha_Bunim_Cohen) (Thursday night shiur 3/12) said to focus on saying berachos while standing or sitting (rather than doing other things).

Comment: @Alex Agreed they are related, though the CDC has officially crowned the coronavirus as a pandemic - more widespread than an epidemic

Comment: I’d think it’s on you to prove that we care about the distinction between a pandemic and an endemic, i.e. “they’re treated differently in regards to X, so are they different here as well?”

Comment: בכל יום תענית שגוזרין על הצבור מפני הצרות. בית דין והזקנים יושבין בבית הכנסת ובודקים על מעשי אנשי העיר מאחר תפלת שחרית עד חצות היום. ומסירין המכשולות של עבירות. ומזהירין ודורשין וחוקרין על בעלי חמס ועבירות ומפרישין אותן. ועל בעלי זרוע ומשפילין אותן. וכיוצא בדברים אלו. ומחצי היום ולערב רביע היום קוראין בברכות וקללות שבתורה שנאמר מוסר ה' בני אל תמאס ואל תקוץ בתוכחתו ומפטירין בנביא בתוכחות מענין הצרה. ורביע היום האחרון מתפללים מנחה ומתחננים וזועקים ומתוודים כפי כחם:

Comment: This means the first thing is to know why it comes. Which when I asked was closed. All these 'segulos' are only after doing tshuva not when still carrying on doing aveiros.

Comment: @NJM the other question says pandemic too